# javascript prompt select a file (no upload, just get file name)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, imacros

I'm mixing javascript and imacros to automate some tasks. 
The main JS file will do some stuff and go to my website in firefox. Then, the script check if the word "confirmation" is found

Here's what i have so far

```
var macro = "CODE:";
(...)  

var big_count=parseFloat(prompt("how many loops ?",100));


for(var x=0;x<big_count;x++)
{
    iimSet("rnd",Math.floor(Math.random()*2000 + 1));
    iimPlay(macro);

    if(window.content.document.body.textContent.contains('confirmation'))
    {
        //if confirmation word found
        iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=60");

    }   
    else
    {
        //if confirmation word isn't found
    }

}
```

If the confirmation word is found, i want to launch another .iim script. I know i can do this using the following:

```
iimPlay("myFile.iim")
```

But the user running the .JS file needs to be able to chose which .IIM file will be run at the end of the script. How can i do this ?
I need some sort of prompt dialog that will list all files inside the following folder:
C:\Users\Libertad\Documents\iMacros\Macros
Then when a file is selected, pass the file name to the iimPlay() function

Comment: use a `<input type=file>`, then look at `input.value` once the user picks something

Comment: it's a .JS file not HTML

Comment: Feel free to contact me via e-mail ( shugarjs@gmail.com ) and I'll help you out with this code.